# Git subl -n -w command not found

Tags: git

I set my git core editor as sublimetext using

`$ git config --global core.editor "subl -n -w"`

I also can use `subl` command to start sublime

But when I try to start sublime using `git commit`

I get this error:

[image: Error]

```
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... subl -n -w: subl: 
command not found
error: There was a problem with the editor 'subl -n -w'.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What happens if you type just `subl` on the command line?

Comment: It starts the sublimetext

Comment: This tends to be a path issue. The way to set the path (or PATH or however your command line interpreter spells it) depends on your command line interpreter. This often depends on your OS as well.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I agree the image is not very clear, but the error message has been copied by the OP, and is available in text form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first your aliases (regular shell aliases, not git aliases)

If `subl` is itself a shell alias, it would not always work when called from a git alias.
If not, check the output of `which subl` to make sure it is in your `$PATH`.

---

The [OP berkegocmen7](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11360589/berkegocmen7) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68534178/git-subl-n-w-command-not-found/68540555#comment121140438_68540555):

> As you say `subl` was a shell alias.

But even un-setting the alias was not enough.

From the [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235345/discussion-between-vonc-and-berkegocmen7):

> I thinks this a problem due to update of sublime
>
> It's updated to SublimeText3 from 2
> Yeah I figured it out: Name of the path has changed because of the update from Sublime2 to Sublime3 that's why the path was broken in `/usr/local/bin`
> I updated that path then it worked

Comment: As you say subl was a shell alias. When I checked the output of  ``` which subl``` it returned the path's itself. I tried to set the code.editor using that path which was ```  git config --global core.editor "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ``` but I still get the same error

Comment: @berkegocmen7 Can you make sure the alias is no longer defined in your current session, and then try again, since subl itself is in your path?

Comment: @berkegocmen7 If you are using the full path, don't forget the `-n -w` options.

Comment: I removed the alias using  `unalias subl`then I tried to set the editor using full path with `-n -w`options. But still the same error

Comment: Can you type `git config --show-origin --show-scope  -l|grep editor`: is there any other editor setting?

Comment: `--show-scope` flag is not working for me. But I tried to set editor as vscode and it worked. Maybe I should just simply delete Sublime and reinstall

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235345/discussion-between-vonc-and-berkegocmen7).

Comment: @berkegocmen7 Well done. I have included your comment and discussion/conclusion in the answer for more visibility.